# Missing <div class="messages error"> on form submit

Tags: forms

I am trying to submit my form. But then the form's required error validation is not adding the class `<div class="messages error">`. Because of that, my error message is not showing in red text formats.

Here is a screenprint of how it looks like (and in which no red text is shown):

[image]

Any suggestions about what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Seems issue with your theme. Try to change the theme and check.

Comment: hi it's working fine on our local environment but when i have moved the code on live sever then error message displaying in this formats . i have viewed the source code then in local server then we found that <div class="messages error"> has append before <h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2> but in live server <div class="messages error"> ii not appended with <h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2>.. what will be main cause ???

Comment: Can't say without looking at it but yeah try to clear browser cache.

Comment: Can you provide more details about (a) how that '<div class="messages error">' gets added in your local envir and (b) what (code?) you actually 'moved' to the live server?

Comment: No feedback on my prior comment? Also, what is the current status of this issue/question?

Comment: Hi thank you very much .. now my live site is working fine there was some problems in includes/theme.inc  file . when i moved   theme.inc file from local environment to live server then it's working  . thank you for your quick response